# How do I remove this faucet handle?

Tags: faucet

[image]

Does anyone know how I can remove this handle? There's no setscrew and it appears to be 1 piece. I tried to pry it off. The drain says it's a Kholer, not sure the drain matches the faucet.

Comment: That appears to be a hex screw inside the open end.  I believe that's a clamp that holds the outer part onto the stem.  Did you try backing that out and seeing if you can remove the handle?

Comment: it is staring you in the face

Comment: Gotta give an up vote we have a clear photo and although the op may not have ever have seen an inset hex screw , the information needed is there to provide an answer @JWH20 make that an answer with some cautions and I will up vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the end where you removed the handle extension there is a brass hex nut.

Loosen that with your hex wrench and you should be able to pull the handle off the stem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that. I didn't want to mess it up if I wasn't supposed to remove the nut. There's actually 2 of them , 1 on each side of the stem.